# Negation of $a < b \leq c$?

Tags: logic

What is the fundamental concept behind it? What is the structure of this proposition? I’ve never seen three relational operators in this form of proposition.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: It’s a conjunction of two relational statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that all of the inequalities $a<b$, $b\leq c$ and $a< c$ need to be satisfied. But, because the first two inequalites imply the third one, it is enough to consider the first two.

So, the inequality $a<b\leq c$ is equivalent with the conjunction
$$a < b \wedge b \leq c$$

To find the negation of this statement, use De Morgan's theorem and you will arrive at
$$a \geq b \vee b > c$$
(The negation of $a < b$ is $a\geq b$ and the negation of $b \leq c$ is $b > c$)

Answer (score 1):

The negation is $a\geq b\lor b>c$.

To get this, use de Morgan's rule to turn the conjugation into the upper statement, where the original expression is $a<b\land b\leq c$.